# How to create relationship based on common Epochtime property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to do a model for state changes of a batch. I capture the various changes and I have an Epoch time column to track these. I managed to get this done with the below code :

```
MATCH(n:Batch), (n2:Batch) 
WHERE n.BatchId = n2.Batch
WITH n, n2 ORDER BY n2.Name
WITH n, COLLECT(n2) as others
WITH n, others, COALESCE(
    HEAD(FILTER(x IN others where x.EpochTime > n.EpochTime)),
    HEAD(others)
    ) as next
CREATE (n)-[:NEXT]->(next)
RETURN n, next;
```

It makes my graph circular because of the HEAD(others) and doesn't stop at the Node with the maximum Epoch time. If I remove the HEAD(others) then I am unable to figure out how to stop the creation of relationship for the last node. Not sure how to put conditions around the creation of relationship so I can stop creating relationships when the next node is null

Comment: In your `WHERE` clause, should `n2.Batch` be `n2.BatchId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
MATCH(n:Batch)
WITH n ORDER BY n.EpochTime
WITH n.BatchId AS id, COLLECT(n) AS ns
CALL apoc.nodes.link(ns, 'NEXT')
RETURN id, ns;
```

It orders all the `Batch` nodes by `EpochTime`, and then collects all the `Batch` nodes with the same `BatchId` value. For each collection, it calls the apoc procedure [apoc.nodes.link](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) to link all its nodes together (in chronological order) with `NEXT` relationships. Finally, it returns each distinct `BatchId` and its ordered collection of `Batch` nodes.